# cocos2d-js moveTo and animate action

Tags: cocos2d-js, cocos2d-html5

I have a moveTo sprite action and I am trying to have the sprite animate while moving. It is a waling animation.

My trouble is I can make the sprite moveTo or animate but not both together so that when the sprite stops moving the animation goes back to the standing frame.

I am using cocos2d-js v3.0

```
this.sprite = new cc.Sprite.create("#player-stand-f-0");
this.sprite.setPosition(new cc.Point(300,300));
this.addChild(this.sprite);

    var animFrames = [];
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        str = "player-walk-f-" + i;
        var spriteFrame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
       var animFrame = new cc.AnimationFrame();
        animFrame.initWithSpriteFrame(spriteFrame, 1, null);
        animFrames.push(spriteFrame);
    }

var animation = cc.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.025);
var animate   = cc.animate(animation);

sprite_action = cc.MoveTo.create(2,cc.p(x,y));
this.sprite.runAction(sprite_action);
this.sprite.runAction(animate);
```

I have also tried the following but the walking would animate once and not continue until moveTo stops.

```
var seq = cc.sequence(animate, sprite_action);
```

Comment: Do the actions work if you call them separately? I mean, have you tried commenting out only one of the `runAction` calls to see if they work as expected if the other one is not called?

Comment: If yes, have you tried `cc.spawn(animate, sprite_action)`? (Offtopic: note that `cc.spawn()` equals `cc.Spawn.create()`, and this is true for all other actions. The `.create()` methods are deprecated)

Comment: yes actions run separately. They run together in the sequence also but the animation only loops once and not for the duration of the move

Comment: Yes I have tried the .spawn and the animation only runs one loop as with sequence

Comment: Bloop. All I can think of is asking in the official forums then. Guys over there have a better understanding of the inner workings of the framework.

Comment: I did yes. No answer though. I would have thought this would come up quite often and have a solution :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use "cc.sequence" action it will animate first then move. But if you want to animate the sprite sheet while moving it, there are two ways to achieve that:Look into "*cc.Spawn*" action. It is used for the purpose just like you need. Another convenient method is to *run two actions concurrently*.. Below mentioned code will give you the idea.

```
    // create sprite sheet
    cc.SpriteFrameCache.getInstance().addSpriteFrames(spritesheet_plist); // add Spritesheet Plist 
    var SpriteSheet = cc.SpriteBatchNode.create(spritesheet_png);  // add Spritesheet Png
    this.addChild(SpriteSheet,1);

    // Push the frames for animation
    var animFrames = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var str = "sequence_" + i + ".png";
        var frame = cc.SpriteFrameCache.getInstance().getSpriteFrame(str);
        animFrames.push(frame);
    }


    // taadaa ...!!  Animate the sprites
    var animation = cc.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.06);
    var sprite = cc.Sprite.createWithSpriteFrameName("sequence_0.png");
    sprite.setAnchorPoint(0.5,0.5); // optional
    sprite.setScale(1.0,1.0); // optional
    sprite.setPosition(widhthPostion, heightPosition);
    sprite.runAction(cc.RepeatForever.create(cc.Animate.create(animation)));
    SpriteSheet.addChild(sprite,1);


    // Move the sprite
    var actionMove = cc.MoveTo.create(duration, cc.p(destinationX, destinationY));
    sprite.runAction(actionMove);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but my question was how would I stop the walking animation once the move is completed? his walking animation should start when the move starts and finishes when he reaches the xy

Comment: Instead of "sprite.runAction(cc.RepeatForever.create(cc.Animate.create(animation)));"

use var animate = cc.RepeatForever.create(cc.Animate.create(animation));

then in move action add call function
var actionMoveDone = cc.CallFunc.create(function(node) {
            sprite.stopAction(animate);
        }, this);
sprite.runAction(cc.Sequence.create(actionMove, actionMoveDone));